# How to deploy vue.js and laravel appllication on shared hosting

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I have an application with Vue and laravel5.6 which is working fine on my virtual machine setup.
What is the way to host it on live shared hosting server.

I got 500 internal server error while accessing it from URL,as there is no routes defined as GET.

Note:The index is coming from the Vue project. Laravel is only API

Comment: Please look for inbound rules of vm .. and add inbound rule for your application

Comment: I believe you've added your APIs are inside routes/api.php. Just add 1 route which will have a GET request inside routes/web.php.

Comment: Can we have some code?

Comment: @GauravDave:Exactly i was thinking this to try

Comment: Have you tried it now? Does it work?

Comment: @GauravDave:Its not working,as i am unable to send request form blade to vue

Answer (score 0):

Like @Gaurave Dave had suggested in the comment section,

you can insert a code in your web.php for all request to go to a view. An example is given below.

```
Route::get('/{any}', function(){
   return view('index');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

so inside your index.blade.php, you can insert your Vue script code or component, this will serve as landing for your Vue app.